# Transpose columns to rows and rows to columns in query result

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2432e0ea4f699157c879ba1565cd2eae)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    product VARCHAR(255),
    sales_date DATE,
    sales_volume INT
);

INSERT INTO sales
(product, sales_date, sales_volume)
VALUES 
("Product A", "2019-03-16", "400"),
("Product B", "2019-03-16", "200"),
("Product A", "2019-03-17", "300"),
("Product A", "2019-03-18", "600"),
("Product A", "2019-03-19", "500"),
("Product B", "2019-03-19", "900"),
("Product A", "2020-03-16", "800"),
("Product A", "2020-03-17", "150"),
("Product B", "2020-03-17", "350"),
("Product A", "2020-03-18", "480"),
("Product B", "2020-03-18", "790"),
("Product A", "2020-03-19", "840"),
("Product A", "2020-03-20", "560");
```

From the table above I want to extract the `sum` of the `sales_volume` `BETWEEN "2019-03-16" AND "2019-03-18"` **(PY)** and `BETWEEN "2020-03-16" AND "2020-03-18"` **(CY)** in order to have a **prior-to-current-year** comparison.

The result should look like this:

```
KPI               PY        CY
sales_volume    1.500     2.570
```

---

With the following query I am getting very close to the result:

```
SELECT

 (CASE
 WHEN DATE(sales_date) BETWEEN "2019-03-16" AND "2019-03-18" THEN "PY"
 WHEN DATE(sales_date) BETWEEN "2020-03-16" AND "2020-03-18" THEN "CY"
 END) AS time,

SUM(sales_volume)
FROM sales
WHERE 
DATE(sales_date) BETWEEN "2019-03-16" AND "2019-03-18"
OR DATE(sales_date) BETWEEN "2020-03-16" AND "2020-03-18"
GROUP BY 1;
```

However, it is strucutred in rows:

```
time    SUM(sales_volume)
CY          2.570
PY          1.500
```

How do I need to change the query above to get the structure as in my expected result?

Comment: I've probably said this before, but seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code. An RDBMS is for the storage and retrieval of relational data, and very little else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation :

```
select 'sales_volume' as kpi,
       sum(case when sales_date >= '2019-03-16' AND 
                     sales_date <= '2019-03-18' 
                then sales_volume else 0 
          end) as PY,
       sum(case when sales_date >= '2020-03-16' AND 
                     sales_date <= '2020-03-18' 
                then sales_volume else 0 
           end) as CY
from sales s;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a certain reason why you use <= and >= instead of BETWEEN?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=031af5f7f052a0b28faadf1f94033e0d